# Running TCL script from JAVA

Tags: java, tcl

I want to run a TCL script out of my JAVA program.
As I want to create a GUI which will start a TCL script in the end.

I have some knowledge of JAVA and none of TCL.

I'm happy about every hint!

Comment: Please read [ask] and [help]. Your question is considered off-topic at StackOverflow and also shows no research effort. So it is likely that it gets down-voted and closed.

Comment: When you ask your question again, be sure to consider whether you want those Tcl scripts to run in the Java process or in their own subprocesses. _This will totally change what answer you get._

Answer (score 1):

Use `ProcessBuilder` for launching the TCL scripts from your java program

[Examples](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-processbuilder-examples/)